# How to change Array of Object into Single object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this sample of code

```
a = [ { "apple" : 1 } , { "orange" : 2 } ]
```

and how would I change this to the following?

```
a = { "apple" : 1,  "orange": 2 }
```

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...a)`.

Comment: How do you want to merge objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for the objects.

```js
var array = [{ apple: 1 }, { orange: 2 }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);
    
console.log(object);
```

ES5 with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var array = [{ apple: 1 }, { orange: 2 }],
    object = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            r[k] = o[k];
        });
        return r;
    }, {});
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.assign.

```js
var a = [ { "apple" : 1 } , { "orange" : 2 } ]


a = Object.assign({}, ...a);

console.log(a);
```